# how can i put h3 and p tag inside one border?

Tags: html

```
<div>
  <span class="brd-box">
    <h3>Garages For</h3><p>Renault KWID</p>
  </span
</div>
<style>
.brd-box {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
```

I want to put `h3` and `p` in a box border with 1px so with span tag and I am unable to achieve it.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language.  Please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 1):

`Span` is `display:inline` by default. So change it to `display:block`

```html
<div>
<span class="brd-box">
<h3>Garages For</h3><p>Renault KWID</p>
</span>
</div>

<style>
  .brd-box {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the class `brd-box` to the span you instead should give it to the `div`

```
<div class="brd-box">
<h3>Garages For</h3>
<p>Renault KWID</p>
</div>
<style>
.brd-box{
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
```